# php script to write files and create zip file

Tags: php, file, string, zip

I'm trying to develop an online formbuilder. Each user can build their own forms and I want to be able to provide a button that when clicked will download the users html form page along with its css file as a zip file.

I know how to zip the files, but my problem is that the main users html form page doesnt exist as seperate file, its url is in a query string such as:

```
 http://localhost/form.php?id=9
```

So was wondering how this could be done

thanks

rifki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `file_get_contents`, `curl`, or `fopen` to write the content of the url to file on disk... then zip that up. Exmaple:

```
$formContent = file_get_contents('http://localhost/form.php?id=9');
$formFile = 'path/to/tmp/form.html';
file_put_contents($formFile, $formContent);

//code to zip up css and form.html
```

Comment: Hey thats great, thanks
but how would I do this for all users without having to repeat the code with different id numbers?

thanks

Comment: You could grab all the ids in an array and loop through it, you could make a function that takes an id or a full url as an argument... or a number of other things.. you didnt really give enough info to answer that effectively.